# Reading A File Name into a PowerShell Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, filenames

I am looking for some help when it comes to using Read-Host.  Here is my issue, I want the user to type in the full file name "blah.txt" how do I store the whole file name into one element of my array?  With what I have I keep getting each character not the whole text.

Thanks

Comment: What *do* you have, actually? We can't help you with your code without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

How are you capturing the array?  Here are two examples that illustrate how you could pull this into an array:

```
#Initialize the array first:
$array = @()
$array += Read-Host "Some Prompt"


#Alternatively, wrap results in array
$array = @(Read-Host "Some Prompt")

#Verify that the whole string is captured as an object in the array
$array[0]
```

Here's [a good source on arrays from PowerShell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/11/chapter-4-arrays-and-hashtables.aspx).  It's specific to PowerShell version 2, but applicable to later versions.

Comment: I am trying to use an $args array and filling it with Read-Host. So `$args = Read-Host "Enter Full File Name"`

Comment: So depending on whether you want to keep what is in args, or add to it...  pretty much the same as above, replacing $array with $args.  $args = @(Read-Host "Some Prompt") #or $args += Read-Host "Some Prompt"... As Adil mentioned $args is an automatic variable, and IMHO you should probably pick another variable name to use - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx

Comment: Just curious, did you know that $args is a special variable (aka automatic variable) that holds unassigned parameters in PowerShell while choosing that as your variable name?

Comment: My hope is going forwards I can use $args to check to make sure users are putting in more files names in at a time for error checking reasons.

Comment: correction, I meant unassigned "arguments". So, when they call your script everything unassigned is already available to you in $args array

Comment: I wonder if I am using $args wrong then.  If I have
`$args = Read-Host "Enter File Names:" ` and a user puts in five file names, how can I check and make sure each entry of the file name is one element and not by each character and has more than the number of files I will want to look at (future use).

Comment: Well, unfortunately you have not provided enough information to answer that. Read-Host just reads input and puts it into a variable. It's up to you to parse that and get the information you need from that. Specifying $args or $xyz does not automatically gives you that and read-host is probably not appropriate for this. Can they not call you script with filenames as parameters?

Comment: @Laitosto: `$args` is an automatic variable containing the arguments with which a script was called. Do not use it like this.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers So if I wanted to have my program check to see if a user is putting in more than three file names have it run the program, but if the user only puts in 2 file names have it do something else.  would this be a good use of running the program using `$args`?

Comment: @Laitosto - you should look into creating an advanced function. [Example post from Jeff Hicks](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/2012/04/powershell-scripting-with-validatecount/) on using ValidateCount.  Also see [About_Functions_Advanced](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847806.aspx),
[About_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx),
[About_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847872.aspx).